# Different security rules for different Firestore collections

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm currently using Firestore for the first time and trying to understand the security rules a bit. I now my question is really simple and that I could figure out an answer by doing a bit more research but I wanted to be sure that I am doing the right thing, so I thought it would be better to just ask here.

If I had two collections in Firestore one called "A" and the other "B" what would my security rules have to be if I wanted just authenticated users to read, write, update, delete... in A and everyone to read in B but just authenticated users to write, update, delete... in B.

Edit:
Here are the current rules they apply the rules for B to all collections:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
   }
```

}

Comment: Please put the Firestore rules in the thread. (i’m on my phone so easier to read it directly from here) and i’ll try to help you out. :)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure    - Here is how you can structure it up. Using the ”match /{}” Something like this: match / {B}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation on authentication in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication), you will find these rules:

> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // Allow the user to access documents in the "cities" collection
>     // only if they are authenticated.
>     match /cities/{city} {
>       allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Modified for your use-case, that'd be something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /A/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /B/{id} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```